# Infinitival and participle complements

Tags: complementation

Which of the following sentence sounds natural and correct and why?

> 1. I can help you practice English.
>      Vs
>      I can help you practicing English.
> 2. Yesterday, I saw the dog bark.
>      Vs
>      Yesterday, I saw the dog barking.

Would this sentence be regarded as correct or wrong?

> I saw Tom helped her yesterday.

Can anyone explain me the structures of the objects of the verbs? Is ‘you’ in the object clause of sentence 1 acting as subject of the gerund or infinitive phrase? 
Also, can anyone explain to me when and how to use bare infinitive verbs as a object of verb phrase?

Comment: This is two quite different questions; since Tᴚoɯɐuo has already addressed the first I have taken the liberty of 'editing out' the second, which appears in the title. You may ask it as a separate question; you may find the tag-wiki on [aspect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info) helpful.

Comment: Can you please answer it here? I don’t know why there seems to be some error while posting the question again.

Comment: What sort of an "error"? I'll be happy to help you post it, if the link I posted doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
I can help
     you 
    (to) practice English
```

*practicing* would not be grammatical there.

But **see** (and other verbs of sensation) allows for the participle:

```
I saw 
   her
   walk  | walking
```

Your example is grammatical:

```
I saw
 (that) Tom helped her yesterday.
```

In lieu of an object like "her" there is a finite clause.

as **saw** can also take a finite clause complement.

and a non-finite clause complement:

```
  I saw
     Tom helping her yesterday.
```

Comment: Note that "I can help you, practicing English" is grammatical, but has a different meaning.  "I can help you, (while I am) practicing English."